# Keyword/phrase extraction from Text using Deep Learning libraries

Tags: neural-network, text-mining, deep-learning, beginner, tensorflow

Perhaps this is too broad, but I am looking for references on how to use deep learning in a text summarization task.

I have already implemented text summarization using standard word-frequency approaches and sentence-ranking, but I'd like to explore the possibility of using deep learning techniques for this task. I have also gone through some implementations given on [wildml.com](http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/) using Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN) for sentiment analysis; I'd like to know how one could use libraries such as TensorFlow or Theano for text summarization and keyword extraction. Its been about a week since I started experimenting with Neural nets, and I am really excited to see how the performance of these libraries compares to my previous approaches to this problem.

I am particularly looking for some interesting papers and github projects related to text summarization using these frameworks. Can anyone provide me with some references?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Google Research Blog](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2012T21) should be helpful in the context of [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/).

In the above article, there is a reference to the [Annotated English Gigaword dataset](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2012T21) which is routinely used for text summarization.

The 2014 paper by [Sutskever et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3215) titled *Sequence to Sequence Learning with Neural Networks* could be a meaningful start on your journey as it turns out that for shorter texts, summarization can be learned end-to-end with a deep learning technique.

Lastly, [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/textsum) is a great Github repository demonstrating text summarization while making use of TensorFlow.

Answer (score 16):

This is an open area of research and it certainly depends on the way you frame the problem. If you're talking about multi-document summarization then the problem is slightly different than if you were talking about single-document summarization.

[It's worth briefly reviewing the literature.](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~afm/Home_files/Das_Martins_survey_summarization.pdf)

The link provided by [u/Society Of Data Scientists](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/26596/society-of-data-scientists) is great and it's useful for the ***abstractive*** summarization task across a single document. There's also work done on ***extractive*** summarizations, which identifies important sentences to extract.

[Rush et. al has a nice paper on the abstractive summarization with Attention](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.00685v2.pdf), which is based on deep learning.

For an extractive summarization, you could use an LSTM to build your classifier and use standard TensorFlow/Torch libraries but there doesn't seem to be any current publications on using deep learning for this approach.

Here are some additional GitHub repos:

- [The Original Rush et. al repo.](https://github.com/facebook/NAMAS)
- [A TensorFlow implementation of the same paper](https://github.com/carpedm20/neural-summary-tensorflow)

Comment: Thanks @franciscojavierarceo I will look into the above mentioned papers.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like this is more extractive summarization if you are looking for key words. Here are a few papers which probably have implementations:

[Neural Summarization by Extracting Sentences and Words](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07252)

[Extractive Summarization using Deep Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.04439.pdf)

[Semi-supervised Convolutional Neural Networks for
Text Categorization via Region Embedding](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.01255.pdf)

Also, SpaCy (not affiliated) has a good [blog](https://explosion.ai/blog/deep-learning-formula-nlp) on the general architecture of of text extraction tasks.