# Keyword Extraction from a text followed by a key value using tensorflow

Tags: python, neural-network, data-mining, tensorflow, text-mining

I have a pdf file that contains information . I would like to extract few key terms/phrase along with a value for example (`current balance : CHF (swiss francs) 1,000`)

I can convert pdf file to text using pdfminer . But how i can extract the above keyword using tensorflow text classification or other methods.

Can anyone suggest how i can start with it? I haven't come across a single example with tensorflow. There is a question here ([Keyword/phrase extraction from Text using Deep Learning libraries](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10077/keyword-phrase-extraction-from-text-using-deep-learning-libraries)
). but this doesn't help me to understand much as I am a beginner.

I used NLTK to tokenize words and read no of words by using

```
import re
text = re.sub(r'[_"\-;%()|+&=*.!?:#$@\[\]/]', ' ', f)
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

tokens = word_tokenize(text)
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
words = [w for w in tokens if not w in stop_words]
freq = nltk.FreqDist(words) 
for key,val in freq.items():
    frq = str(key) + ':' + str(val)
```

So i have this text that i could like to extract the key phrase `current balance : CHF (swiss francs) 1,000` along with the value using Neural Network. How can i do that? I came across many posts but couldnt get what i need.

PS: every time i upload a new file, i want my algorithm to find out the same keyword and use the value next to it.